# Foreach array merge

Tags: php, arrays, merge, array-merge

I am trying to merge multiple array with a foreach loop. The *wp_get_nav_menu_items()* function returns an array object by filling in the menu name. With my loop I want to add all the array items of the 3 menus together.

```
$menus = array( 'menu 1', 'menu 2', 'menu 3' );
foreach( $menus as $key => $menu ) {
    $menu_object    = wp_get_nav_menu_items( esc_attr( $menu ) );
    $menu_objects[]     = $menu_object;
}
```

But with my current code I get the following result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => WP_Post Object
                (
                    [ID] => 397
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => WP_Post Object
                (
                    [ID] => 112
                ) 
        )
)
```

And I need this:

```
Array
(
     [0] => WP_Post Object
        (
           [ID] => 397
        )
     [1] => WP_Post Object
        (
           [ID] => 112
        )
     [2] => WP_Post Object
        (
           [ID] => 136
        )
)
```

So I have tried to use *array_merge* in the loop but this doesn't work.

```
$menus = array( 'menu 1', 'menu 2', 'menu 3' );
foreach( $menus as $key => $menu ) {
    $menu_object    = wp_get_nav_menu_items( esc_attr( $menu ) );
    $menu_objects   = array_merge( $menu_objects, $menu_object );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only needed to specify *$menu_objects* as an array:

```
$menus = array( 'menu 1', 'menu 2', 'menu 3' );
$menu_objects = array();
foreach( $menus as $key => $menu ) {
    $menu_object    = wp_get_nav_menu_items( esc_attr( $menu ) );
    $menu_objects   = array_merge( $menu_objects, $menu_object );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just modify this line to get the object:

```
$menu_object = wp_get_nav_menu_items( esc_attr( $menu ) );
```

Try something like:

```
$menu_object = wp_get_nav_menu_items( esc_attr( $menu ) )[0];
```

Comment: No this way I only get the first array of each menu.